# Accessing elements in an iFrame (ie9, Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm having some trouble with this seemingly simple task.

1. I want to load the current url into an iFrame.
2. I need to access several divs and remove them.
3. I need to Print the modified iFrame ONLY.

Here is what I have so far, but I am unable to access any html elements in the loaded iFrame. The iFrame's contents do print as expected, but I need to remove several divs which I am pulling my hair out trying to do:

```
var newWidth = "1024px";
var url = window.location;
var $iFrame = $('<iframe id="printFrame" style="width:' + newWidth + ' !important;     height:100 !important; border: 1px solid #000000;" name="printFrame"></iframe>');

$('#content-area').append($iFrame);

$iFrame
  .load(function () {

   // NEED TO DO THIS IN THE IFRAME DOCUMENT: 
   // $('#content-area').remove();
   // CANT FIGURE OUT HOW


   this.contentWindow.print(); // this prints fine
   $(this).unbind('load');
   })
   .attr('src', url);
```

Thanks!
Ron

Comment: it should be the responsibility of the page loading in the iframe to style itself for printing via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it with JavaScript? Use a print style sheet to hide the elements that you do not want printed.

Add an new stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Add rules that you want applied *print.css*

```
div.noPrint { display : none; }
```

If you still want to do it with an iframe, you need to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to access the elements.

```
var iframeDivs = $iFrame.contents().find("div");
```

Comment: It is a long explanation why I can't use the stylesheet approach, but help me understand how I make the same call you cite within the iFrame load function:

Comment: Do you not see the last line? That is how you access the iframe contents.

Comment: display : none  does hide the div, but it leaves 220px of blank space where it used to be when printing in ie9.

Comment: this does not work: $iFrame.contents().find('#content-area').remove();

Comment: if I do this: var divs = $iFrame.contents().find('div')     then do alert(divs.length)    I get 0, even though there are close to 50 at least.

Comment: it seems like even though I'm in the .load handler, the html isn't available yet?